# phonegap config.xml file for new app

Tags: php, cordova

I'm new to this this coding world. Using phonegap I have developed (using Php) an app for online Shopping and uploaded it into the play store.

Now i have developed a second one with the same config.xml as in my first app. But I have changed the name and description for second app. But whenever I want install the second app, it's not installing. When i remove the first app then it will install & viceversa.

As per my knwledge I need to do change the config.xml. kindly guide me do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors? How does your config looks like? `Not installing` is a very poor information.

Comment: Jst App cannot install error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change **id** attribute in widget tag of **config.xml**. 
You can not install two app with same **ID**.

Comment: I vl try, thanks man

Comment: Thnks man. it s wrkng nw